# No module named 'cv2' even though I installed it

Tags: python, opencv

I installed opencv-python with the command `pip install opencv-python` when I imported it and wrote c it didn't show me to autofill the writing so I just typed `import cv2` by my own and then `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` but it still didn't want to autofill after the cv2.Vid python version 3.9.13

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Comment: i tried importing pygame to see if it works but it s still the same thing

Comment: it works though with already installed modules like time

Answer (score 3):

The Python error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'" occurs for multiple reasons:

1. Not having the opencv-python package installed by running pip install opencv-python.
2. Installing the package in a different Python version than the one you're using.
3. Installing the package globally and not in your virtual environment.
4. Your IDE running an incorrect version of Python.
5. Naming your module cv2.py which would shadow the official module.
6. Declaring a variable named cv2 which would shadow the imported variable.

you can try to install using these.

```
# ️ in a virtual environment or using Python 2
pip install opencv-python

# ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)
pip3 install opencv-python

# ️ if you get permissions error
sudo pip3 install opencv-python

# ️ if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable
python -m pip install opencv-python

# ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)
python3 -m pip install opencv-python

# ️ for Anaconda
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Comment: Thanks I was using Pyenv so I just had to use the right command and install package to the right version its working now